# pandas: .isna() shows that whole column is NaNs, but it is strings

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with a column that is populated by "yes" or "no" strings.
When I do `.value_counts()` to this column, i receive the correct distribution. 
But, when I run `.isna()` it shows that the whole column is NaNs.

I suspect later it creates problems for me.

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[0,1,2,3,4],[40,30,20,10,0], ['yes','yes','no','no','yes']]).T, columns=['A','B','C'])

len(df['C'].isna())  # 5 --> why?!
df['C'].value_counts()  # yes : 3,  no: 2 --> as expected.
```

Comment: Because `df['C'].isna()` returns a series of 5 booleans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`len` gives you the length of the Series (irrespective of its content), not the number of `True` values.

Use [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.sum.html) if you want the count of `True`:

```
df['C'].isna().sum()
# 0
```